# How to fix broken/loose clips in the holding bracket of Conair 134 wall-mounted hair dryer

Tags: bathroom, repair, mounting

I have a Conair 134 wall-mounted hair dryer, which is working perfectly but has two broken clips in the holding bracket so now the dryer is very loose when put back in the bracket. Is there a way to salvage this situation instead of getting a new unit?

[image: Conair 134]
[image: Conair 134]

Comment: why not move and than mount it to a horizontal surface? Or install a buckle strap (like on fire extinguisher wall mounts).

Comment: Barring finding replacement parts (seems unlikely, but I haven't looked - I assume you have) probably not. Few consumer appliances are repairable these days, if only by not providing any replacement parts. You might get someone with a 3D printer to print up some parts that might work, but unless that's "for fun, for free (or a beer)" it's not cost effective *.vs.* replacement.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I was afraid so. A replacement isn't expensive but it just feels so wrong & wasteful.

Comment: @ojait Horizontal surface is limited resource on our small bathroom countertop:) The hair dryer taken down is too bulky (two part) to use as a standalone unit. But buckle strap seems an interesting idea to explore.

Comment: or small bungee.

Comment: you could glue a supermagnet to the side of the hair dryer and glue a second supermagnet, or just a piece of metal, to the holder

Comment: make  blocks that fits into the opening in the picture ... use springy foam, like a pool noodle or old flipflop sandals ... if it holds the hair dryer, then glue the blocks into place ... if you don't have foam, then test the idea using cardboard ... if it works, then look for foam

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we don't do small appliance repair here.

Comment: @FreeMan I feel that it's more about a DIY mounting solution rather than fixing the (small appliance) hair dryer itself. By the way, is there a scope description somewhere?

Comment: [Scope, rules for asking/answering/etc](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help). It's been the general consensus that small appliance repair is OT. However, larger things like fridge, stove, furnace, (i.e. more "permanent", not counter top) appliances are on topic. It can be confusing for a new person, or someone with 10k rep...

Comment: @jsotola Gluing something is what I had in mind but struggled to think of the right materials. Thanks for both brilliant suggestions. I have small magnets, so I'm going to try that route first.